# Count a specific value disregarding repeating dates

Tags: excel, excel-2010

First time post, lots of help over the years though--I've seen some articles dealing with my problem but am having a block for some reason & thought it best to just ask...

I have a list of students in column A, classes, such as Math or English in column B, & the dates of said classes in column C.

I'm looking for a formula that will count all the classes that took place for a specific subject.  So if there are 10 names in column A & the same date for all 10 in column C, it's counting it as 10 separate classes, rather than 1 class for 10 people.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to count the distinct dates?

Comment: Somewhat, I need to count distinct dates against the class names.  So basically all distinct dates for Math, all distinct dates for English, etc..  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF("subject"=$B$2:$B$99,1/(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$99,"subject",$C$2:$C$99,$C$2:$C$99)),))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: replace "subject" with a reference to the particular subject you wish to count distinct class dates for.

Note: replace the 99s with a row number deep enough to accommodate your data.

Note: the formula assumes you have column headers in the first row and that the data begin on the 2nd row.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion easier, and very much more versatile, would be to use a PivotTable. This would allow a lot of additional analysis, such as by week/month/year or by Student, etc and can show the results for all classes at one time without a change of parameter:

[image]